# Multimonth Calendar and Selected Dates Scenario with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-plugins

I am trying to demonstrate a web site scenario on my own.
What i want to do is a multimonth calendar which can be filled with special days with a css class.

I googled it and find some Js calander controls with customizable css.But i wanted to ask it first before i start coding and probably be wasting my time.

Kind regards,
Barbaros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may checkout [jQuery DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/). It can display multiple months and comes with different CSS themes which you could personalize.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Darin, i guess i am going to use the display inline and Display Multiple Months.